# Minimum time control

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Given the dynamical system : $ \dot{x}_1=x_2\\
\dot{x}_2=u\\
\dot{x}_3=x_4\\
\dot{x}_4=\alpha x_3+\beta x_4 + u  $

where $\alpha,\beta \in R-\{0\}$ and $|u| \leq 1$. My goal is to find the minimum time control $u$ to bring all the states to the origin from an initial position $x(0)=(x_{i} \ 0 \ 0 \ 0)^T$ where $x_i >0 $. Is this system made of two decoupled subsystems? I found a minimum time controller for the states $(x_1,x_2)$ but doesn't work for $(x_3,x_4)$. Is this problem solvable at all?

EDIT : I know the minimum time controller for the system : $\dot{x}_1=x_2\\
\dot{x}_2=u $

I have verified that such controller does not work for the larger system, and I know that the minimum time controller is also unique, so can I say that the there is no optimal controller for the main system?

Comment: Since you have the same input to both subsystems, you need to apply the method on the complete system.

Comment: Please, would you take a look at my edit?

Comment: The minimum time controller is unique for a system. If you change system, it will also be unique but that minimum time will be different. So, if you control the first part, you may get $T_1$ as minimum time, but $T_2$ if you control the whole system. There is no reason that $T_1=T_2$. Have you checked whether your system is controllable?

Comment: Yes it is indeed controllable. Yes, the theory says that for non-positive eigenvalues there are at most (n-1) swithces. In the larger system, I've been able to show that actually there can be only two switches, and I've found an optimal controller with two switches for the double integrator. What you are saying is that the controller I've found may not be the only one in this case?

Comment: You are nowhere asked to control the double integrator only. You are asked to control the entire system. So, you need to use the approach on the entire system.

Comment: Many thanks for your patience and maybe what I'm trying to say isn't clear. The optimal solution is unique. Now, I have the optimal solution $u^*$ for the double integrator. This means that whatever $u \ne u^*$ I plug in, it  won't achieve the desired behavior,doesn't it? And since $u^*$ does not work for the states $(x_3,x_4)$, does this mean that I can't solve the problem? What am I missing?

Comment: What you are missing is that you do not seem to read what I am writing. The control input that drive the whole system in minimum time does not coincide to the one that drives the two first states only.

Comment: Are there constraints, such as on the control input $u$? And is it the case that $\alpha\neq0$?